# keeping formulas after using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I am trying to keep the formulas in the tables I'm using after using power query. I've noticed that every time I load any table into power query, all the formulas get erased. Is there anyway to keep the formulas after using power query editor?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, this isn't possible. Power Query will wipe them out every time. It's been brought up and my understanding is there is currently no plan to change this functionality. The sister functionality of standard queries returning to Tables will honor your formulas. It's a little confusing why some do and some don't.

I recommend putting those formulas in the query itself, or use a tertiary Table for your calculation(s).

Comment: Teylyn!! Yes, indeed! Good to see you as well! Trying to get back into the swing of things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column to the right of the table that Power Query loads. This Column will always be placed to the right "outside" of the PQ table.

You cannot reference this column within PQ, but you can reference it using Excel Table calcs i.e.  =Table[Column] so its good for final pass analysis